# install pymedia and python audio tools

Tags: macos, mac, installation, python

I noticed a pattern of errors while trying to install PyMedia and Python Audio Tools.  For both modules I run the following:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Then I get a series of compilation errors, and then this:

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/Kx/Kxxj4868HGi6VMhZLPyZN++++TI/-Tmp-//cch1y9AO.out
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5, and this happens whether I'm using gcc-4.0 or gcc-4.2, Mac-Python 2.5 or 2.6, and MacPorts-Python 2.6.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the following from the terminal before issuing the command:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 CFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp" 
export CCFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" 
export CXXFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" 
export LDFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
```

These were my default settings if something needed to compile on the box.
Hope this brings you closer to a working install !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the setup process is attempting to combine several binaries into a fat binary using the `lipo` tool. The error occurs when `lipo` encounters a file whose type it does not recognize.

There's not much more that can be said without a log of the specific commands executed during the setup process.

You might want to try running `file` on the file that `lipo` complains about to see whether `file` can identify the file type. `ls -lh` might also be a good idea; it's possible the file is empty for some reason.